# Flutter device dependant layout with one class?

Tags: flutter, responsive-design

I am trying to do a layout like this:

[image: The layout I am trying to do]

The layout class I am trying to do is as follows:

```
class Layout extends StatefulWidget {
  @required
  final String title;
  @required
  final Widget leftView;
  @required
  final Widget rightView;

  const Layout({Key key, this.title, this.leftView, this.rightView})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  _LayoutState createState() => _LayoutState();
}

class _LayoutState extends State<Layout> {
  String title;
  Widget leftView;
  Widget rightView;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var screenSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(title),
      ),
      drawer: (screenSize.width < Constants.MOBILE_WIDTH_SIZE
          ? DrawerPage()
          : null),
      //TODO: Need to be able to change based on some global variable as comments section can't have something else down there
      floatingActionButtonLocation:
          screenSize.width < Constants.DESKTOP_WIDTH_SIZE
              ? FloatingActionButtonLocation.miniEndFloat
              : FloatingActionButtonLocation.miniCenterFloat,
      body: getRelevantLayout(screenSize.width, screenSize.height),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          // Add your onPressed code here!
        },
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
        //backgroundColor: Colors.orangeAccent,
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget getRelevantLayout(double _width, double _height) {
    if (_width < Constants.MOBILE_WIDTH_SIZE) {
      // mobile Layout
      return leftView;
    } else if (_width < Constants.DESKTOP_WIDTH_SIZE) {
      // tablet layout
      return Row(
        children: [
          DrawerPage(),
          Expanded(
            child: leftView,
          ),
        ],
      );
    } else {
      // desktop layout
      return Row(
        children: [
          DrawerPage(),
          Flexible(flex: 9, child: leftView),
          Flexible(flex: 10, child: rightView),
        ],
      );
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    title = widget.title;
    leftView = widget.leftView;
    rightView = widget.rightView;
    super.initState();
  }
}
```

The idea I was trying to do is in my original routes set up my views i.e

```
      routes: {
        '/': (context) => Layout(
              title: '$_title - Home',
              leftView: ListSectionView(),
              rightView: WhatsNewView(),
            ),
```

Then my idea was to in say the leftview, to set up the rightView, although clearly unless leftview is set up again, it won't work. Only when it is in tablet or phone view do I wish to do the usual Navigation.push

I have tried my best to find a solution like this but to no avail. So any suggestion on how this could be achieved would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I've gone using this as inspiration for now https://github.com/roughike/adaptive-master-detail-layouts. Not ideally what I want but will see how far it can go

Comment: This package may be interesting https://pub.dev/packages/responsive_scaffold

Comment: @pavel thanks but it seems this is just multiple scaffolds and something similar to what I have previously linked. The idea was to use the same scaffold so the bar at the top stretches the screen

Answer (score 0):

I like to make the whole widget tree for each orientation in a separated widget and choose which one to use based on screen width and orientation. I use constants for the sizes of the screen and functions when i want to resize only a few components. Ex:

```
const double smallScreenWidth = 360.0;
const double mediumScreenWidth = 412.0;
const double bigScreenWidth = 480.0;

double iconSize(BuildContext context) {
  double screenWidth = 1;

  if (MediaQuery.of(context).orientation == Orientation.portrait)
    screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
  else
    screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;

  if (screenWidth <= smallScreenWidth)
    return 32.0;
  else if (screenWidth <= mediumScreenWidth)
    return 40.0;
  else
    return 48.0;
}
```

Comment: @rar0x thanks I certainly do stuff similar to this but my main issue is, I wanted the 3 screens to be aware of where it was. I guess, I may have to just try what I am doing as I don't think anyone can see it. My main issue was I didn't want to get extra data from the API until it opens the page.

Comment: I have an app with similar behavior. I only use navigation when the size of the screen is small. When it is big, I show everything in the same screen. It works perfectly. You can do aditional API calls only if needed to build the extra part (your right screen).

Comment: do you just do drawer and leftView (using this example) though?

Comment: You can do the three views. For the third view you would use FutureBuilder (or StreamBuilder) or any other widget that builds itself based on a future result. Then you can call the API only when the third view is needed. You decide to have the third view or not based on screen width.